# Silverstripe - Better way to delete Dataobjects instead of using custom sql querys

Tags: php, silverstripe

Is there a better way deleting dataobject older than x-days instead of using custom sql queries?

that's what I do now

```
    $host = 'localhost';
    $username = 'db123';
    $password = 'pass';
    $db_name = 'db123';

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $sql = "DELETE FROM Cart WHERE Created < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    mysql_close();
```

Comment: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/sqlquery

Comment: thx, i'll have a look

Comment: ummm... why aren't you using SilverStripe's ORM? Or are you really using SilverStripe?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

first of all, using `mysql_query` is **bad**, not just in this case.
`mysql_query` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

secondly, SilverStripe already has a DB connect, do not attempt to create another one.
SilverStripe offers many ways to query the database.

---

**Option 1:**

the cleanest way of course is to use the SilverStripe ORM.
A `DataObject` has a method called `->delete()`.
Using delete has several advantages over writing your own SQL query.

- its easy
- it will delete the DataObject from all its tables for you (eg the DataObject class `Folder` is a subclass of `File`, so if you do `$myFolder->delete()` it will go and delete this `Folder` in the `File` Table but also in the `Folder` Table (if there is a `Folder` table))
- it will execute the SilverStripe delete hooks (`onBeforeDelete` and `onAfterDelete`)

its pretty straight forward:

```
// to delete all `DataObject`s in a List, just loop it and call ->delete()
foreach($list as $item) { 
    $item->delete();
}

// there also is a method that does that for you, however, I would advise against it
// because it is currently inconsistently implemented and might lead to unexpected results
// $list->removeAll(); // i STRONGLY RECOMMEND AGAINST THIS
// if $list is a DataList, it will delete all records
// if $list is a ManyManyList, it will unlink all records
// if $list is a ArrayList, it will error because there is no removeAll() method on ArrayList
```

to solve your problem:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("now -1 day"));

$list = Cart::get()->filter('Created:LessThan', $date);

foreach($list as $item) { 
    $item->delete();
}
```

it however has also a major disadvantage when deleting many `DataObject`s: performance.
I will however still recommend using `->delete()` if you can say that performance is not a huge problem. The benefits usually outweigh the drawbacks.

Read more about `DataList`, `::get()`, `->filter()` and `->delete()` in the SilverStripe docs for [Datamodel / ORM](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/datamodel) and [DataObject](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/dataobject)

---

**Option 2:**

if you however really need to, it is possible to use a lower level of the ORM to perform the delete:

```
$query = new SQLQuery();
$query->setDelete(true);
$query->setFrom('Cart');
$query->setWhere('Created  < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)"');
// if you want to debug the query, you can use ->sql() to get it as string
// echo $query->sql();
$query->execute();
```

Read more about `SQLQuery` in the [SilverStripe docs](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/sqlquery)

---

**Option 3:**

if you for some reason really want to avoid the ORM at all, SilverStripe also lets you execute raw SQL queries:

```
 DB::query("DELETE FROM Cart WHERE Created < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
```

Comment: that's great thank you.
A custom sql query was the first thing which came into my mind. but that's (Option 1) much better.